# Multihilo con configuración, con hilos que pueden estar activos o no. Como robustecerlo

Tags: c#, hilos, servicio

Tengo un **servicio de Windows** que tiene que ejecutar como **máximo 10 hilos** en paralelo, cada uno de estos hilos lee una información y la guarda en la BBDD.

Podría darse el caso que al leer la información del dispositivo, esté caído. Es por esto que tiene que ser un hilo por dispositivo para que un dispositivo apagado o con problemas no pare la lectura del resto.

Además cada uno de los hilos puede estar trabajando o no en función de una configuración que esta en la BBDD, es decir en la base de datos se guarda para cada dispositivo si se ha de leer o no, y que información recuperar del dispositivo.

Cada minuto tengo que leer de la base de datos la información referente a la configuración para cada uno de los hilos.

En el `OnStart` tengo definido lo siguiente:

```
                cargaConfiguracion();
            TimeSpan tsInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, periodoEjecucion, 0, 0);
            IntervalTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(
                new System.Threading.TimerCallback(callBack)
                , null, tsInterval, tsInterval);
```

En carga de configuración cargo la información necesaria para saber que dispositivos y que información cargar y luego llamo al método `callback` que es el que cada "periodoEjecucion=1minuto" volverá a leer la configuración.

Lo que necesito consejo es para como y donde seria lo mejor lanzar el proceso multifloro.

Ahora mismo estoy haciendo pruebas y es lanzando lo siguiente después del código anterior:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => tareaPruebaHilos(i), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Current);
        }
```

siendo la funcion de pruebas una funcion que unicamente mete un log en la base de datos

```
 private static void tareaPruebaHilos(int hilo)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Libreria.SQL_DAL.anadirLog("HILO Nº(" + hilo + ")");
        }
    }
```

En producción la función `tareaPruebaHilos` tendrá otro nombre y comprobara con lo cargado de la configuración si tiene que hacer algo o no, y me preocupa que al hacerlo con un `while(true)` este infinitamente sin hacer nada hasta que en la configuración le vuelvan a indicar que lea de su dispositivo.

No se si seria interesante en caso de que no tenga que leer nada de un determinado dispositivo dentro del `while(true)` añadir un `thread.Sleep` o para pararlo unos segundos. No se que impacto tendría esto con 10 hilos.

El servicio deberá funcionar durante meses o incluso años sin ser reiniciado.

Agradecería que me indicaseis si este planteamiento es robusto y que problemas pueden aparecer.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: informacion de que dispositivos leeria? y que respuesta devuelve la tarea si el dispositivo no funciona? Me parece que deberias plantear el problema con la situacion real en el codigo, porque solo grabar un log seria facil, debes contemplar que pasa cuando te rompe algo para probar bien el codigo.

Comment: @RamiroBarone gracias por el interes. Los dispositivos son unos PLCs que a veces puede que esten conectados o no, existe una libreria (varias en realidad) para este tema y no me preocupa porque ya he leido varias veces de PLCs. Lo que mas me preocupa es el rendimiento y que no se muera en algun momento por algun motivo que no alcanzo a ver.

Comment: No tienen eventos las librerias para detectar cuando sucede algo, le avise a tu codigo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La instrucción while(true) sí supone una carga para el procesador que, efectivamente, como tu mismo mencionas, queda bastante aliviada con un tiempo de espera (Thread.Sleep(1000);) por pequeño que sea.

Tu mismo puedes hacer la prueba. Ejecuta un código como éste, y mira la carga de tu procesador mientras lo ejecutas. A simple vista podrás apreciar picos de procesador mayores en la primera ejecución (sin sleep) que en la segunda.

```
    TimeSpan tsControlTiempos;

    if (first)
    {
        first = false;
        lblMensaje.Text = "Iniciando secuencia de espera SIN Sleep - 10 segundos";

        Application.DoEvents();

        DateTime dtInicio = DateTime.Now;

        while (true)
        {
            tsControlTiempos = DateTime.Now - dtInicio;

            if (tsControlTiempos.TotalSeconds >= 10) { break; }
        }

        lblMensaje.Text = "Fin secuencia inicial";
    }
    else
    {
        first = true;
        lblMensaje.Text = "Iniciando secuencia de espera CON Sleep - 10 segundos";

        Application.DoEvents();

        DateTime dtInicio = DateTime.Now;

        while (true)
        {
            tsControlTiempos = DateTime.Now - dtInicio;

            if (tsControlTiempos.TotalSeconds >= 10) { break; }

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        lblMensaje.Text = "Fin secuencia inicial";
    }
```

Un artículo interesante que viene más o menos a cuento:
https://lapasiondepensar.wordpress.com/2018/09/28/ciclos-reloj/

Saludos.

Comment: La pregunta no solo es la carga en el procesador.